# using something similar to res render in jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

When i load my app i use a route system like this:

```
 router.get('/home', verifyAuth, function (req, res) {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posts')
    .then(resposta => {  
      res.render('home', { info: resposta.data })
    })
    .catch(erro => { 
      res.render('error', { error: erro, message: 'Error' })
    })

});
```

but in my html i have some buttons that trigger this function

```
  var array= new Array()
function myFunc(test){ 
    array.push(test)  
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/posts/filter/",
        contentType:"application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({myArray: array}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ 
            //res.render('home', { info: data })
         }
      });   
}
```

How can i do something like what it is in the `success` of the ajax?

Comment: Please provide a properly detailed explanation of what you are wanting to accomplish

Comment: @charlietfl i dont know if i can be more clear than that. Every time i click in a button i triggered myFunc that will store the value to the array. After that through ajax i will send the array to be used in a controller that will return to me data(this part works). What i want to know is if there is a way to pass the data that arrives in the success of ajax to my html like i do with express with the res.render. I cant explain better than this

Comment: Loop over the data and generate the required html. Can also use a template engine client side

Comment: @charlietfl i was hoping there was another way :/. The html code i have to generate its quite extense and its actually pug/jade. It would be easier if there was something like what i was trying to achieve

Comment: Can use jade as template engine client side also